# parse site registration and push notification

Tags: xamarin, parse-platform, push-notification, xamarin.android

while am trying to sign up to parse site, i cant able to find the option for sign up.

we have to implement parse push notification feature in xamarin mobile application development.

Please guide if any one have idea about registering to parse and the steps to work with push notifications too.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Parse (the service) is no longer available, its last day was Jan 30th 2017. [Here's](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/) the first announce they made back in Jan 26 2016. They gave a whole year to every developer with hosting solution in Parse to be able to migrate it.

Parse became an open source project known as [Parse-Server](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/wiki). You can use this but it will have to be as a self-hosted service.

If you don't feel like hosting Parse there are out there a few solutions that could get you running with for the Push Notifications. Just to name a few you have: Azure now known as [Mobile Center](https://mobile.azure.com/login), you have [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/), Amazon [SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/) and a few others.